# How to get random value from Dictionary<string, bool>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to get a random game name from my Dictionary Dictionary<string, bool>.
Any method I try doesn't seem to work for some reason.
I could do this in simple list form and I had this actually but what I am trying to do is in the first scene I want players to choose games they want to play(1 game or multiple games or all games). I have these game names as buttons on the scene in unity and What I'm trying to do is once they click those buttons and hit play only those games should run.

[This is the screenshot of my main scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM2sM.png)

[Tried with ElementAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JLPw.png)

```
    Dictionary<string, bool> nameOfTheGame = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    nameOfTheGame.Add("Never Have I Ever", false);
    nameOfTheGame.Add("Randomiser", false);
    nameOfTheGame.Add("Dare", false);
    nameOfTheGame.Add("Vote & Win", false);
    nameOfTheGame.Add("Who Is Most Likely To ?", false);
    nameOfTheGame.Add("Where's the water ?", false);
    nameOfTheGame.Add("Would You Rather Choose ?", false);
    nameOfTheGame.Add("Flip Or Strip", false);
    nameOfTheGame.Add("Two Truths And One Lie", false);

    string gameName = //(here)
```

Comment: The answers so far are not taking the fact you're programming for Unity in to account. The error you're receiving is because the compiler can't determine if you mean `System.Random` or `UnityEngine.Random`. Regardless of that issue, I really think you should rethink your approach. It looks like you might be wanting to record which games have already been played? And then are you going to try and save (serialise) this? And using the game name like this is just opening yourself to issues. Would it not be better to use a list so you can order the games list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code using `ElementAt`

For the sake of testing purposes, I have changed a few values to true in your dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, bool> nameOfTheGame = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

nameOfTheGame.Add("Never Have I Ever", true);
nameOfTheGame.Add("Randomiser", false);
nameOfTheGame.Add("Dare", true);
nameOfTheGame.Add("Vote & Win", false);
nameOfTheGame.Add("Who Is Most Likely To ?", true);
nameOfTheGame.Add("Where's the water ?", false);
nameOfTheGame.Add("Would You Rather Choose ?", true);
nameOfTheGame.Add("Flip Or Strip", false);
nameOfTheGame.Add("Two Truths And One Lie", true);
Random rand = new Random();
int index1 = rand.Next(0, nameOfTheGame.Count);
var item = nameOfTheGame.ElementAt(index1).Value;
int index2 = rand.Next(0, nameOfTheGame.Count);
var item2 = nameOfTheGame.ElementAt(rand.Next(0, nameOfTheGame.Count)).Value;
```

Comment: For some reason Random rand = new Random();
and rand.Next are coming up with an error
Unfortunately, it won't let me attach a screenshot.
I have posted a screenshot in my post

Comment: @Pyromancer Random is  to generate the random index

Comment: @Pyromancer you have to show the error message? And please avoid posting images. You should provide text

Comment: I'm sorry I tried text but I was crossing the word limit.
Im new im still trying to learn stackover flow.

Cannot declare a variable of static type 'Random'.

Cannot create an instance of the static class 'Random'

'Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and no accessible extension method 'Next' accepting a first argument of type 'Random' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Question is about Unity, better to use Random.Range(0, nameOfTheGame.Count);

Comment: @Pyromancer do you have `using System;` at the top of the file?

Comment: Fact is, he likely also has UnityEngine, that one also contains a Random class. It would have to be System.Random rand = new System.Random(); which is fine but Unity devs tend to rely on the UnityEngine.Random class.

Comment: from the doc "Name resolution ambiguity
Because the classes share the name Random, it can be easy to get a CS0104 "ambiguous reference" compiler error if the System and UnityEngine namespaces are both brought in via using. To disambiguate, either use an alias using Random = UnityEngine.Random;, fully-qualify the typename e.g. UnityEngine.Random.InitState(123);, or eliminate the using System and fully-qualify or alias types from that namespace instead."

Comment: @Everts you’re right, but you’d also need to tweak it to either `using Random = UnityEngine.Random` at the top, or `var index = UnityEngine.Random.Range ( 0, nameOfTheGame.Count );`

Comment: alright so using System.Random rand = new System.Random(); fixed my problem and @Nino adding using System; is giving me additional errors.
Just one last thing how do I get the random value on a string variable ? 
unfortunately I do not understand this set of code

Comment: @Pyromancer great. Everts and Milan explained everything regarding System.Random and UnityEngine.Random

Comment: well, this code is pretty self explainatory. I answered few minutes later with a bit different approach and with some explanations. Maybe that can help you

Comment: @Pyromancer so using `System.Random` should solve your issue

Comment: @viveknuna seems like Pyromancer should better stop here and go back to some basics :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using `System.Random` class:

```
System.Random rand = new System.Random();
int index = rand.Next(map.Count-1);
string name = map.ElementAt(index).Key;
```

First line initializes random number generator. Second line gets number from 0 to your dictionary length, minus one. Your dictionary has 9 entries, so generated number will be from 0 to 8. Then, by that generated bumber (index) you can get element from your `Dictionary`. Once you have an element, `Key` contains the name of the game.